# What is the difference among these 3 food items: Flattened Rice, Chiwda and Poha?

Tags: rice

In India, Poha is a famous dish especially served as breakfast.

I would like to know if Poha is the name of the dish or Flattened rice or Chiwda.

[image: Flattened Rice]

Answer (score 3):

In India, flattened rice are Poha. Now poha/flattened rice come in packets with the picture you have put. There are a lot of recipes which we make from flattened rice.
Interestingly the most common recipe is known as 'poha'. Here the flattened rice are soaked in water and then they are heated in oil with spices, onion and/or potatoes.
Here is the [recipe](https://www.indianhealthyrecipes.com/poha-recipe-kanda-batata-poha/)
This is a very popular recipe in Maharshtra and basically almost all Indians prefer this recipe for breakfast.
Now flattened rice are also used to make chiwda.
This is rather crunchy, unlike poha.
It is used as an in between meals' snack.
Here generally, the flattened rice are roasted or fried.
Now interestingly the **varieties** of flattened rice for making poha and chiwda are different.
For making poha and **fried** chiwda  the flattened rice are long narrow type.
And for making **roasted** chiwda flattened rice is wider.
Hence, to summarise, the term 'poha' is both flattened rice, as well as a recipe made from flattened rice. Chiwda on the other hand is different.
If you go to an Indian restaurant and ask for poha, they will give you a dish made from flattened rice/poha.
On the other hand if you go to a grocery shop and ask for poha they will give you flattened rice.
I hope your doubt is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Flattened Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flattened_rice) also known a Poha is an ingredient in making [Poha the recipe](https://www.indianhealthyrecipes.com/poha-recipe-kanda-batata-poha/).

"It is also called "beaten rice", **not to be confused with poha**, a Central-West Indian dish prepared **using this flattened rice as the key ingredient**."

It also seems to be one ingredient in Chiwda, at least in [one recipe](https://www.vidhyashomecooking.com/chivda-namkeen-chiwda/) I found.